# How can I force a value to be moved from an inner scope to an outer instead of borrowing?

Tags: rust

I'm newbie in Rust. How can I force a value to be moved from an inner scope to an outer instead of borrowing?

```
let mut r_buf = BufReader::new(file.unwrap());
let mut eof = false;

while !eof {
    let piece = r_buf.fill_buf();
    if piece.is_ok() {
        let mut piece = piece.unwrap();
        let piece_len = piece.len();

        if opt.compress {
            let deflated = deflate_bytes(piece);
            if deflated.is_none() {
                panic!(format!("Cant deflate file {}", path.to_str().unwrap_or("")));
            }

            let deflate_unwrapped = deflated.unwrap();
            let deflate_deref = deflate_unwrapped.deref();
            piece = deflate_deref;
        }
        /* bf: &mut BufStream<File>*/
        let w = bf.write(piece);

        if w.is_ok() {
            written_bytes = w.unwrap();
        }
```

I can't move `&[u8]` from `deflate_deref` to `piece`. I've tried `Vec<u8>` and `Box<&[u8]>`. I have an error "deflate_unwrapped does not live long enough"... I can't operate by `[u8]` type because it doesn't have an exact size in compile type, while references I can only borrow...

In this case must I use something specific or rewrite this code?

Playground link http://is.gd/u8wfm7

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's going to be *very* difficult to help you as we can't compile your code to get the same error! Please read about creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case, it needs to produce the same error you are seeing. Ideally, you'd have something that works on the [playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/), but that might be difficult if you are using external crates. Just try to make the problem as **small** as possible!

Comment: thanks for reply, add link to play.rust-lang.org. I'm thought it's more theoretical problem

Comment: `foo.deref()` is better written `&*foo` in general. You also often won’t need the `&*` at all, e.g. method calls do autoderef and autoref.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let’s reduce your code to a truly minimal example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = {
        let b = 42;
        &b
    };
}
```

For this is what your case is boiling down to: trying to take a reference to something and storing that reference after the original object has passed out of scope.

There are two main ways of dealing with this:

1. Change the scope of the variable that you are taking a reference to:

   ```rust
   fn main() {
       let b;
       let a = {
           b = 42;
           &b
       };
   }
   ```

   So long as you are not dealing with crossing function boundaries (that is, returning a reference to something inside the function) or certain combinations with loop boundaries, this is typically the best solution.
2. Don’t take a reference, but rather do what processing you wish to do with it at the time:

   ```rust
   fn main() {
       let a = {
           let b = 42;
           b.clone()
       };
   }
   ```

   In your particular case, that could be turning the `&[u8]` into a `Vec<u8>`, which can be written `Vec::from(slice)`. Of course, in your specific example you would still need to worry about storing the vector somewhere as in the first way, or else using `Cow<[u8]>` for the whole thing.

There is an article that I have written which among other things considers these questions which you might find helpful: http://chrismorgan.info/blog/rust-fizzbuzz.html. It deals with `String` and `str` where you are dealing more with `Vec<u8>`/`Bytes` and `[u8]`, but the concepts are very much the same.